# convert datetime string to date string

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to convert the dateTimezone string to only date string using regex or some other way.

`"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00"` should be returned as string `"2015-08-18"`

Please help

Comment: why regex? Unless you're worried about the y10k problem, just use whatever ruby's equivalent of `substr()` is.

Comment: Unless you're getting the string from an outside source and are concerned that it might not contain a date, just use `str[0...10]`

Comment: @MarcB, you may have stumbled onto a business opportunity.

Comment: @cary: I'm more worried about the y2038 problem.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
require 'date'

Date.parse("2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00") # => #<Date: 2015-08-18 ((2457253j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.parse("2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00").to_s # => "2015-08-18"
```

I don't normally rely on `parse` because it can be confused by alternate formats, and it slows down the parsing as it tries to figure out the format. Instead, using `strptime` is a good alternative:

```
Date.strptime("2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00", '%Y-%m-%d') # => #<Date: 2015-08-18 ((2457253j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Or:

```
Date.strptime("2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00", '%F') # => #<Date: 2015-08-18 ((2457253j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

And, all can be used with `to_s` to return the string version, since that is what `to_s` is for.

Using Date is the preferred way to do conversions, but you *can* do:

```
"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00"[/^([^T]+)/, 1] # => "2015-08-18"
```

Or even more simply:

```
"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00"[/^[^T]+/] # => "2015-08-18"
```

Or, dispensing with the regular expression entirely, simply slice the string:

```
"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00"[0, 10] # => "2015-08-18"
"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00"[0 .. 9] # => "2015-08-18"
```

Or the more convoluted:

```
"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00".split('T').first # => "2015-08-18"
```

Comment: No.. I need to return it as string only like "2015-08-18"

Comment: And how does the second form converting it to a string not do that?

Comment: without parsing to Date first and then converting to string I guess we can remove that strings after "T" and return date

Answer (score 1):

most simple way is:

```
"2015-08-18T04:55:00+00:00".to_date.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex?

```
([-0-9])T
```

Get the first group.

I suspect this is a http://xyproblem.info/ situation, though.